# How to add/cache Windows domain user profile remotely?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, windows-domain

I have a Windows 10 PC connected in domain, with local administrator account access and need to add a domain user profile in the PC. It's a remote PC and needs VPN to connect to the Domain Controller network. Please suggest how to add a domain user profile to the PC. Given Switch user option is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is cache a specific domain user onto the PC then the answer is very straight forward. Use Microsoft Remote Desktop to remote into that PC just once and the user becomes cached onto the system.